# Word for someone who diverts

Tags: single-word-requests

As the title says, I'm looking for a word for "someone who diverts". I could not find "Divertor" or "Diverter" in the dictionaries I trust or even the Google `define` search query. Merriam-Webster was asking me to subscribe to their Unabridged edition but I'm still unsure if they would have it.

I did find a definition at [Your Dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/diverter) though:

1. A person or thing that diverts or is diverting.
2. A valve used to change the flow of fluid through a system of pipes.

I'm doubting the word is a real English word.

My context:

`He is a diverter from the path of the Lord.`

Just to clear the context, I'm referring to someone who diverts others from the path of the Lord since the person who himself has diverted would be an apostate. [Thanks to @DanBron for suggesting this clarification]

Thanks for your time.

Comment: *Diverter* [is a legitimate word](http://www.onelook.com/?other=web1913&w=Diverter). Bear in mind that dictionaries can't possibly, and therefore do not, list every possible derivative of some stem. Speaking in general terms, so long as you employ standard, productive morphological rules, you can form words as you please and you'll be fine. Having said that, if you really want to see some supper before using a possible neologism, you may like a couple cool tools: [onelook.com](http://onelook.com) to search many dictionaries simultaneously, and a corpus like Google nGrams or the COCA.

Comment: Is it limited to American English?

Comment: I see no annotations in the dictionary entry to suggest that. That said, I just did a couple quick searches in the BNC (BrE) and COCA (AmE) corpora, and *diverter* does seem more prevalent in there latter than the former. In both cases it's used more frequently as an adjective (*diverter valve*) than as a noun (*wind diverter*), and frequently, maybe universally, to refer to devices rather than persons.

Comment: I have trouble finding the term in [Oxford's Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com).

Comment: It is actually not commonly used to refer to a person: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=diverter&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdiverter%3B%2Cc0. Could ***entertainer*** fit your context? http://www.thefreedictionary.com/entertainer

Comment: @Josh61 I imagine he means someone who is diverting attention, creating a distraction, rather than entertaining.

Comment: ***Distractor***: a person or thing that distracts the attention. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/distractor

Comment: @Josh61, I don't think ```distractor``` works here since he will distract from one goal to anything else; whereas a diverter will move your attention from one goal to another. Even the spell check feature on this site has problems with both divertor and diverter.

Comment: @KhalidHussain Ah, your additional context clears things up quite a bit.  Worth including it from the get-go for future questions. The word you want is ***apostate***.

Comment: I'm not sure about your definition of diverter: ***Divert***
3. To entertain by distracting the attention from worrisome thoughts or cares; amuse. See Synonyms at amuse. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/divert

Comment: @DanBron, no; I wish to refer to the person who is diverting others and not he himself an apostate. I don't know if I could use divert as a noun.

Comment: @KhalidHussain That's helpful additional detail worth adding to your question.

Comment: @DanBron - would you use   the  example sentence in writing or speaking?

Comment: @Josh61 Most assuredly not: I'm an atheist ;)

Comment: @DanBron - and as a language 'enthusiast'?

Comment: @Josh61 I have no problem with *diverter* as a noun. However, my instinctive reading of that sentence was to interpret *divert* intransitively; I imagined Khalid was talking about a man who had himself diverted: an apostate.  My general preference is to use specific terms of art or nomenclature where they are available, and since this kind of person and behavior must have been discussed frequently over the last two millennia of high religion, I imagine such a specific term likely exists. If I were going to answer this question, my approach would be to seek that word.

Comment: Do you mean a "*militant atheist*" or a "*tempter*"?

Comment: @Graffito *Tempter* is good! I'm not sure *militant atheist* will work: surely a evangelical Christian who converts a Muslim is a *diverter* in the eyes of Islam? Also, I just found out the Catholics call such a person a *scandalizer*. Interesting!

Comment: "Diverter" is a perfectly fine word, and is used in many different contexts.  The little knob on top of the tub faucet in most US bathrooms is a "diverter".

Answer (score 3):

**[aberrant:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/aberrant)** departing from the right, normal, or usual course.

> *'An [aberrant Christian](http://www.deceptioninthechurch.com/terms.html)'* , *'an aberrant doctrine'*

**[heretic:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/heretic)** a professed believer who maintains religious opinions contrary to those accepted by his or her church or rejects doctrines prescribed by that church.

Comment: *heretic* is much better than the phrase "a lost cause" ;)

Answer (score 2):

***Edit*** - (after the question had been edited) - Are you looking for **"a subverter of the faith"?**

> - subverter - one who undermines the moral principles of (a person, etc); corruptor

If you're looking for **"someone who diverts"**, meaning "amuse",

since we cannot add a sufix to "divert-" so as to get what you're looking for, I suggest you use the word **entertainer**.

> - divert - to entertain by distracting the attention from worrisome thoughts or cares; amuse. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/divert)
> - entertain - to hold the attention of (someone) with something amusing or diverting. See Synonyms at amuse. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/entertain)

Comment: Someone who diverts from the path to the Lord is an entertainer? Well, so long as he does it in an amusing way, why not? ;)

Answer (score 1):

***Seducer***   "to lead astray, as from duty, rectitude, or the like; corrupt."  [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/seducer)

This assumes that the example you gave "a ___ from the path of the Lord" is typical of the use you want.  If you want a use that said that X diverted Y from a disastrous mistake, then seducer would not be right.

Answer (score 0):

How about **tempter** or **temptation**?

> [**tempt**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tempt?s=t): to entice or
>   allure to do something often regarded as unwise, wrong, or immoral

Your example:

> He is a **tempter** from the path of the Lord.
>
> OR
>
> He is a **temptation** from the path of the Lord.

A **tempter** or **temptation** does not so much *divert* as *pull away* from the path of the Lord. That may better reflect the sense you're seeking.

**Tempter** fits well in the sense that it has obvious religious connotations and associations, e.g., Eve **tempted** by the serpent in the Garden of Eden, Jesus **tempted** by Satan while fasting in the desert for forty days and forty nights. Ditto re **temptation**.